# Template class without a name

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a class that uses a template, but I can't get rid of this error:

`8:1: error: template class without a name`

My code is as follows:

```
#ifndef BST
#define BST

#include <utility> 

template <typename DataType>

class BST
{
  ...
};
```

The error occurs at `class BST` I'm pretty sure Datatype is a name. Am I missing how templates work?

Comment: `#define BST` `class BST`

Comment: Best to use something like `#ifndef BST_HPP` or `...BST_HEADER` to avoid things like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preprocessor line

```
#define BST
```

is messing you up.

Change it to something like:

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H

#include <utility> 

template <typename DataType>

class BST
{
  ...
};
```